# Which differential forms commute with the curvature form?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature, differential-forms

Consider a vector bundle, $E \to M$, with connection, $\nabla$, and curvature $2$-form, $F$ on $M$.  For $E$-valued differential forms on $M$, $\Omega(M, E)$, we have an exterior covariant derivative, $d_{\nabla}$ for which $d_{\nabla}^2 = F \wedge (-)$.

Question: What is the significance of the collection of forms, 
$$\{ \omega \in \Omega(M, E) \ | \ F \wedge \omega = 0 \}?$$

Comment: I would say these forms annihilate, not commute.

Comment: In the context where, locally, the forms take values in some lie algebra that wedge becomes a wedge-bracket and since I think of bracketing as being motivated from the commutator... hence the name.  But sure.  Either context could be helpful!